# Excel: Any way to show a sheet in "full screen" type mode?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with a bunch of graphs on it and it'd sure be nice to have a VBA function of some sort to Sheets("Graphs").Activate and then have it go into some sort of full-screen mode so I can see all the graphs more clearly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is:

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
```

and

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
```

Comment: How would this work? I set it to true when going to the graph sheet? And then how do I turn it off again when the user decides to stop viewing the graphs?

Comment: @user2777137 you need to right click the sheet name and select view code then insert `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
End Sub`

Comment: When testing it, I used an ActiveX toggle button, as that seemed the most appropriate control type, on the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Button should suffice or why not link to a Function key as a Toggle?
I have written Full Screen Excel boilerplate Code which you can use to build a complete Workbook that can be toggled in & out of Full Screen Mode (you could add in as many Charts as you like).

You can find it here:
http://www.kubiszyn.co.uk/deprecated/software-kioskv6dev.html

Scroll to the bottom of this article for beta Code that will eventaully work for all Excel Versions 9-15 including Excel 2013 64bit.

I also have a free AddIn here:
http://www.kubiszyn.co.uk/deprecated/software-kiosk4.1.html

Thanks, Mark